# Is there a faster lm function

Tags: r, lm

I would like to get the slope of a linear regression fit for 1M separate data sets (1M * 50 rows for data.frame, or 1M * 50 for array). Now I am using the `lm()` function, which takes a very long time (about 10 min).

Is there any faster function for linear regression?

Comment: You're complaining about ten minutes?  Unbelieveable.  Parallelize the calculations if the 1M data sets are independent.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to a dataset of 1M rows or 1M separate datasets? If it's the latter, maybe you should think about the data fishing implications of what you are doing first.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry for confusing. My dataset is about 1 M * 54. I already parallel them with 16 cores. I understand 10 min is not a big problem. Just try to find a faster way for linear regression.

Comment: @thelatemail It is 1 M separate datasets.

Comment: If you are only worried about the slope. It looks like you could calculate it directly using `sd` and `cor`. Check out this [post](http://statistics.about.com/od/Descriptive-Statistics/a/Slope-Of-Regression-Line-And-Correlation-Coefficient.htm). Slope = r*(sdy/sdx)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. yes I just need the slope.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes there are:

- R itself has `lm.fit()` which is more bare-bones: no formula notation, much simpler result set
- several of our [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html)-related packages have `fastLm()` implementations: RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen, RcppGSL.

We have described `fastLm()` in a number of blog posts and presentations.  If you want it in the fastest way, do not use the formula interface: parsing the formula and preparing the model matrix takes more time than the actual regression.

That said, if you are regressing a single vector on a single vector you can simplify this as no matrix package is needed.

Comment: There is also a `speedglm` package, no idea how much faster (if any) it is, though.

Answer (score 17):

Since 3.1.0 there is a `.lm.fit()` function. This function should be faster than `lm()` and `lm.fit()`.

It's described and its performance is compared with different `lm` functions here - https://rpubs.com/maechler/fast_lm.

[image]

Comment: What if I want to use a model with random effects? Anything fast and able to deal with large datasets?  lme4 is very slow and needs a lot of memory.

Answer (score 8):

lmfit in the package [Rfast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfast/index.html) is even faster than .lm.fit.
The only drawback is that it does not work when the design matrix does not have full rank.

Answer (score 6):

`speedlm` from `speedglm` should do it as it works on large data sets.