# How to calculate the average slope within a moving window in R

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

**My dataset** contains 2 variables **y and t [05s]**. y was measured every 05 seconds.

I am trying to calculate the average slope within a moving **20-second-window**, i.e. after calculating the first 20-second slope value the window moves forward one time unit (05 seconds) and calculates the next 20-second-window, producing successive 20-second slope values at **05-second increments**.

**I thought** that calculating a rolling regression with rollapply (zoo package) would do the trick, but I get the same intercept and slope values for each window over and over again. What can I do?

My data:

```
dput(DataExample)
structure(list(t = c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 
0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 
1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55, 
1.6, 1.65, 1.7, 1.75, 1.8, 1.85, 1.9, 1.95, 2, 2.05, 2.1, 2.15, 
2.2, 2.25, 2.3, 2.35, 2.4, 2.45, 2.5, 2.55, 2.6, 2.65, 2.7, 2.75, 
2.8, 2.85, 2.9, 2.95, 3, 3.05, 3.1, 3.15, 3.2, 3.25, 3.3, 3.35, 
3.4, 3.45, 3.5, 3.55, 3.6, 3.65, 3.7, 3.75, 3.8, 3.85, 3.9, 3.95, 
4, 4.05, 4.1, 4.15, 4.2, 4.25, 4.3, 4.35, 4.4, 4.45, 4.5, 4.55, 
4.6, 4.65, 4.7, 4.75, 4.8, 4.85, 4.9, 4.95, 5, 5.05, 5.1, 5.15, 
5.2, 5.25, 5.3, 5.35, 5.4, 5.45, 5.5, 5.55, 5.6, 5.65, 5.7, 5.75, 
5.8, 5.85, 5.9, 5.95, 6, 6.05, 6.1, 6.15, 6.2, 6.25, 6.3, 6.35, 
6.4, 6.45, 6.5, 6.55, 6.6, 6.65, 6.7, 6.75, 6.8, 6.85, 6.9, 6.95, 
7, 7.05, 7.1, 7.15, 7.2, 7.25, 7.3, 7.35, 7.4, 7.45, 7.5, 7.55, 
7.6, 7.65, 7.7, 7.75, 7.8, 7.85, 7.9, 7.95, 8, 8.05, 8.1, 8.15, 
8.2, 8.25, 8.3, 8.35, 8.4, 8.45, 8.5, 8.55, 8.6, 8.65, 8.7, 8.75, 
8.8, 8.85, 8.9, 8.95, 9, 9.05, 9.1, 9.15, 9.2, 9.25, 9.3, 9.35, 
9.4, 9.45, 9.5, 9.55, 9.6, 9.65, 9.7, 9.75, 9.8, 9.85, 9.9, 9.95, 
10, 10.05, 10.1, 10.15, 10.2, 10.25, 10.3), y = c(3.05, 3.04, 
3.02, 3.05, 3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.05, 3.02, 3.01, 3.04, 3.04, 3.03, 
3.03, 3.03, 3.02, 3.02, 3.03, 3.03, 3.03, 3.04, 3.03, 3.03, 3.03, 
3.03, 3.02, 3.02, 3.02, 3.01, 3.03, 3.03, 3.03, 3.03, 3.03, 3.02, 
3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.02, 3.03, 3.02, 3.02, 3.01, 
3.01, 3.02, 3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.02, 3.02, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 
3.02, 3, 3.01, 3.02, 3.02, 3.02, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.02, 
3, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3, 3, 3.01, 3, 3, 3.01, 
3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3, 3, 3, 3.01, 3, 3, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 
3.01, 3.01, 3, 3.02, 3, 3.01, 3.02, 3.04, 3.05, 3.08, 3.04, 3.06, 
3.08, 3.06, 3.08, 3.09, 3.04, 3.05, 3.07, 3.08, 3.06, 3.08, 3.08, 
3.07, 3.08, 3.08, 3.05, 3.06, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 
3.08, 3.08, 3.05, 3.06, 3.08, 3.08, 3.06, 3.09, 3.07, 3.08, 3.08, 
3.08, 3.06, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.09, 3.07, 3.07, 3.08, 3.08, 
3.06, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.09, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 3.08, 3.07, 
3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.08, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.08, 3.07, 3.07, 
3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.08, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.08, 3.06, 3.07, 3.06, 
3.07, 3.06, 3.08, 3.07, 3.07, 3.06, 3.07, 3.06, 3.07, 3.06, 3.07, 
3.06, 3.07, 3.06, 3.06, 3.06, 3.07, 3.04, 3.04, 3.04, 3.06, 3.06, 
3.04, 3.04)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-207L), .Names = c("t", "y"))
```

**R-Code**:

```
require(zoo)
library("zoo", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
rollapply(zoo(DataExample),
          width=5,
          FUN = function(Z) 
          { 
            z = lm(formula=y~t, data = as.data.frame(DataExample)); 
            return(z$coef) 
          }, by=1,
          by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

Comment: Please `dput(DataExample)` your data.

Comment: Sorry for my naive question, but how can I do this on stackoverflow?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Type dput(mydata) and paste that into your question. If there is too much data make a sample.

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average-in-r)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense...Do you have an idea about how I canchange it to fit "moving subsets"? I thought that rollapply would to the moving part... Or do I need a completely new approach?

Comment: Calculating the slope for 5 datapoints, then moving forward one time unit and calculatig the slope for the next 5 datapoints... I don't know if I make myself clear ;)

Comment: @Zheyuan Li -  Sorry, i kind of overlooked the second part of your answer... I've tried it out... It does the trick, you're awesome!! Thank you so, so much!! ( :

Comment: @Zheyuan Li  That is so nice of you, but I would rather vote your comment/answer up ;) I am new to stackoverflow and not sure how to do it. Maybe you can post the answer to the question and I can vote your answer up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment seems to have been deleted but it was pointed out that the function in rollapply in the code in the question was not using the argument passed to it.  After fixing that and making some other minor improvements, this returns the intercept and the slope in columns 1 and 2 respectively.

```
library(zoo)

Coef <- function(Z) coef(lm(y ~ t, as.data.frame(Z)))    
rollapplyr(zoo(DataExample), 5, Coef, by.column = FALSE)
```

Comment: As shared by Jot eN [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820005/2444948), `lm` is pretty slow. Use `.lm.fit` instead. For example `coef(.lm.fit(cbind(1, t), y))` for your example. Or `coef(.lm.fit(cbind(1, t), y))[2]` to get the slope.

Answer (score 4):

Here a complete code to illustrate what I was meaning with the speed of `.lm.fit` and `lm`. 
As well as a usage with data.table.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(microbenchmark)

# function for linear regression and find the slope coefficient
rollingSlope.lm <- function(vector) {

  a <- coef(lm(vector ~ seq(vector)))[2]
  return(a)

}

rollingSlope.lm.fit <- function(vector) {

  a <- coef(.lm.fit(cbind(1, seq(vector)), vector))[2]
  return(a)

}

# create data example
test <- data.table(x = seq(100), y = dnorm(seq(100), mean=75, sd=30))
ggplot(test, aes(x, y))+ geom_point()
```

[image]

```
# graphics about the slope calculated
test[, ':=' (Slope.lm.fit = rollapply(y, width=5, FUN=rollingSlope.lm.fit, fill=NA),
             Slope.lm = rollapply(y, width=5, FUN=rollingSlope.lm, fill=NA))]
# change the width size
test[, ':=' (Slope.lm.fit.50 = rollapply(y, width=50, FUN=rollingSlope.lm.fit, fill=NA),
             Slope.lm.50 = rollapply(y, width=50, FUN=rollingSlope.lm, fill=NA))]
# melt data for plotting
test2 <- melt.data.table(test, measure.vars=c("Slope.lm.fit", "Slope.lm", "Slope.lm.fit.50", "Slope.lm.50"))
ggplot(test2, aes(x, value))+ geom_point(aes(color=variable))
```

[image]

```
# efficiency of the 2 lm
mb <- microbenchmark(lm.fit = a <- rollapply(test$y, 5, rollingSlope.lm.fit, fill=NA),
                     lm = b <- rollapply(test$y, 5, rollingSlope.lm, fill=NA))
# check if they equal
all.equal(a, b, check.attributes=FALSE)
    # TRUE
# plot results
boxplot(mb, unit="ms", notch=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about doing it without the zoo library

```
## Modified version of your function that does not rely on accessing
## variables that is external to its environment.
slopes<-function(data) { 
            z = lm(formula=y~t, data=data ); 
            z$coef ## Implicit return of last variable
}

## The number of frames to take the windowed slope of
windowsize<-4

do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(dim(data)[1]-windowsize),
                     function(x) slopes(data[x:(x+windowsize),])))
```

It iterates over a list from 1 to `length data` - `windowsize` subsetting `data` into overlapping window sizes of 4. The subsetted data is then passed to your slopes function before being bound into a single array.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to plot slopes as `geom_segment()` but I failed. At least I've got the df with different values for slope:

```
slope <- function(dat){
        return(data.frame(t = sprintf("[%f,%f]", min(dat$t), max(dat$t)),
                          slope = lm(y~t-1, data = dat)$coef, 
                          row.names = NULL)
               )
}

mw <- function(dtf, wdth = 0.2, incr = 0.05){
        if(!nrow(dtf)){
                return(data.frame())
        }
        return(rbind(slope(dtf[dtf$t <= min(dtf$t) + wdth,]),
                mw(dtf[dtf$t >= min(dtf$t) + incr,])
                )
        )
}


slp <- mw(dtf)
head(slp)
tail(slp)

#                    t     slope
#  1 [0.000000,0.200000] 20.180000
#  2 [0.050000,0.250000] 16.498182
#  3 [0.100000,0.300000] 13.433333
#  4 [0.200000,0.400000]  9.554737
#  5 [0.250000,0.450000]  8.299608
#  6 [0.300000,0.500000]  7.340606
#    ...
#175 [9.900000,10.100000] 0.3049778
#176 [10.000000,10.200000] 0.3017733
#177 [10.050000,10.250000] 0.3002829
#178 [10.150000,10.300000] 0.2982748
#179 [10.250000,10.300000] 0.2958620
#180 [10.300000,10.300000] 0.2951456
```