# How to resample and remodel n times by vectorization?

Tags: r, regression, vectorization, lm, statistics-bootstrap

here's my for loop version of doing resample and remodel,

```
B <- 999
n <- nrow(butterfly)
estMat <- matrix(NA, B+1, 2)
estMat[B+1,] <- model$coef

for (i in 1:B) {
resample <- butterfly[sample(1:n, n, replace = TRUE),]
re.model <- lm(Hk ~ inv.alt, resample)
estMat[i,] <- re.model$coef
}
```

I tried to avoid *for* loop,

```
B <- 999
n <- nrow(butterfly)

resample <- replicate(B, butterfly[sample(1:n, replace = TRUE),], simplify = FALSE)
re.model <- lapply(resample, lm, formula = Hk ~ inv.alt)
re.model.coef <- sapply(re.model,coef)
estMat <- cbind(re.model.coef, model$coef)
```

It worked but didn't improve efficiency. Is there any approach I can do vectorization?

---

Sorry, not quite familiar with StackOverflow. Here's the dataset *butterfly*.

```
colony  alt precip  max.temp    min.temp    Hk
pd+ss   0.5 58  97  16  98
sb  0.8 20  92  32  36
wsb 0.57    28  98  26  72
jrc+jrh 0.55    28  98  26  67
sj  0.38    15  99  28  82
cr  0.93    21  99  28  72
mi  0.48    24  101 27  65
uo+lo   0.63    10  101 27  1
dp  1.5 19  99  23  40
pz  1.75    22  101 27  39
mc  2   58  100 18  9
hh  4.2 36  95  13  19
if  2.5 34  102 16  42
af  2   21  105 20  37
sl  6.5 40  83  0   16
gh  7.85    42  84  5   4
ep  8.95    57  79  -7  1
gl  10.5    50  81  -12 4
```

Comment: In the data you showed, there is `alt` column, is that the same as `inv.alt`?

Comment: column _inv.alt_ is inverse of column _alt_

Comment: "No for loop" != "vectorized". I guess the difference in running time between for-loop version and `lapply` version would not be too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming `butterfly$inv.alt <- 1/butterfly$alt`)

You get the error because `resample` is not a list of resampled data.frames, which you can obtain with:

```
resample <- replicate(B, butterfly[sample(1:n, replace = TRUE),], simplify = FALSE)
```

The the following should work:

```
re.model <- lapply(resample, lm, formula = Hk ~ inv.alt)
```

To extract coefficients from a list of models, `re.model$coef` does work. The correct path to coefficients are: `re.model[[1]]$coef`, `re.model[[2]]$coef`, .... You can get all of them with the following code:

```
re.model.coef <- sapply(re.model, coef)
```

Then you can combined it with the observed coefficients:

```
estMat <- cbind(re.model.coef, model$coef)
```

---

In fact, you can put all of them into `replicate`:

```
re.model.coef <- replicate(B, {
    bf.rs <- butterfly[sample(1:n, replace = TRUE),]
    coef(lm(formula = Hk ~ inv.alt, data = bf.rs))
})
estMat <- cbind(re.model.coef, model$coef)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does fix the error. But my ultimate intention is to improve efficiency, now I know lapply is not vectorization.

Comment: @LadyChili, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416413/is-there-a-faster-lm-function.