# How to run linear regression model for each industry-year excluding firm i observations in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, linear-regression, panel-data

**Here is the dput output of my dataset in R......**

```
data1<-structure(list(Year = c(1998, 1999, 1999, 2000, 1996, 2001, 1998, 
1999, 2002, 1998, 2005, 1998, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1998, 2000), 
    `Firm name` = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", 
    "E", "E", "F", "F", "G", "G", "H", "H"), Industry = c("AUTO", 
    "AUTO", "AUTO", "AUTO", "AUTO", "AUTO", "AUTO", "AUTO", "AUTO", 
    "Pharma", "Pharma", "Pharma", "Pharma", "Pharma", "Pharma", 
    "Pharma", "Pharma"), X = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), Y = c(30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 
    38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), Z = c(23, 
    29, 47, 53, 59, 71, 77, 83, 89, 95, 107, 113, 119, 125, 131, 
    137, 143)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L), class = "omit"))
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), Z = c(23, 
29, 35, 41, 47, 53, 59, 65, 71, 77, 83, 89, 95, 101, 107, 113, 
119, 125, 131, 137, 143)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L), class = "omit"))
```

Here I am trying to regress `Y~ X+Z` for each industry year but excluding firm i observations.For each firm I want to estimate the linear regression model **using all industry peer firms' observations but excluding firm's own observations**.For example;for firm A, I want to regress Y~ X+Z by using all observations of its industry peer firms (B,C & D) across time but excluding firm A observations. Similarly I want to run model for firm B by using all observations of firm A,C & D (part of same industry as B) across time excluding firm B observations. And same procedure for firm C & D as well. I want to do this exercise for every firm within each industry. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @bonedi you can use a nested loop to accomplish this. If you want to create models for individual industry-year combinations, you will need to subset your data by `Industry` and `Year`. You can loop over `Firm name` and exclude that firm before creating the model. Results can be stored in a list, named by industry-year-firm. It's not a pretty solution but it should get you closer.

```
lst <- list()

for (ind in unique(data1$Industry)) {
  for (year in unique(data1[data1$Industry == ind, ]$Year)) {
    for (firm in unique(data1[data1$Industry == ind & data1$Year == year, ]$`Firm name`)) {
      sub_data <- data1[data1$Industry == ind & data1$Year == year & data1$`Firm name` != firm, ]
      if (nrow(sub_data) > 0) {
        name <- paste(ind, year, firm, sep = '-')
        lst[[name]] <- lm(Y ~ X + Z, data = sub_data)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There would be a nice tidyverse approach to the multiple equations. First, A loop could make n data frames with a column that stated which firm was excluded, with each data frame excluding firm i, then row bind to one data frame, and pass to the tidyverse multiple equations code. A side bonus is that the data and models would be ready for ggplot().

Comment: @Ben...Thanks for the help. I was able to work with nested loop. The only thing is my dataset is slightly heavy & using 3 nested loops is taking a lot of time to execute. So is there a way to make the above nested loop code more efficient or robust??

Comment: Have you looked into a faster `lm`? See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416413/is-there-a-faster-lm-function

Answer (score 0):

The displayed code isn't nice to read. But from what you write, I'd recommend a nested loop, e.g:

```
for(y in year){
    for(comp in FirmName){
      # transform data : select only companys in this industry, but exclude comp
       lm(..)
     }
 }
```